# Removing Newsletter Subscription popup on loading of the website in magento

Tags: magento

I had purchased a theme for Magento and installed it, but on loading of the website it shows an popup to subscribe for the news letter and i want to disable it. please help me

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the phtml file from which it is called. there will be some jQuery/JS code, which you just need to comment.